# Looking to complete an Else If statement

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

Wanting to create a new If Else statement that categorizes by two conditions from different columns. The first one is IsAdult and some of the values have 'adult' in them which is why I used contains; same goes for 'clipped' under the ISCLIPPED column.

I know this may be a syntax error.

```
if (ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'clipped') 
   then ('Adult Clipped')
else if (ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'Not Clipped')
  then ('Adult Not clipped') 
else ('NA')
```

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: XQE-V5-0017 V5 syntax error found for data item 'calculation-new' of query 'validateQuery', invalid token "and" found after "if (ISADULT contains 'adult') ".

Comment: It expected "then" and found "and".  Correct your parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'clipped')) 
then ('Adult Clipped')
else (
    if ((ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'Not Clipped'))
    then ('Adult Not clipped') 
    else ('NA')
)
```

But that logic won't work because 'Not Clipped' contains 'Clipped' so that would also produce 'Adult Clipped'.

How about this?

```
if ((ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'Not Clipped')) 
then ('Adult Not clipped')
else (
    if ((ISADULT contains 'adult') and (ISCLIPPED contains 'clipped'))
    then ('Adult Clipped') 
    else ('NA')
)
```

And since you're using IF-THEN-ELSE rather than CASE-WHEN-THEN-END, there may be a concern about case-sensitivity -- depending on how Cognos decides to process it.

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I changed it to if it contains 'not' for that recommendation. I appreciate it.